# How to merge two audio outputs to one output

Tags: microphone, audio-interfaces

I'm trying to merge two audio outputs which are my microphone and VB-Audio Virtual Cable, to one output, and maybe make one of the outputs quieter when my microphone is making sound. I'm looking for a solution which does everything on the fly, no recording.

Comment: Same company - https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/ - I've never tried it, I don't use Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The function that achieves this is called an audio mixer.

You need an audio mixer to take these two inputs and mix them down to a single output at the requisite level.

Comment: @quest In old times there was only 1 mic, no other signals got amplification. The singer used it. But today it's common to have more. You need just now a 2 input mixer, but it's wise to have some room to expand the system. For ex. this mixer will not get too small as soon as you one day must connect a few mics more: https://worldaudioconcert.com/xl4/